# Vercel node dependencies are not installed

Tags: node.js, configuration, vercel

I am trying to deploy on vercel a `node.js` `express` app. However, I am getting `ERROR Cannot find module` - despite them being listed in the `package.json`.

---

The initial deploy was successfull. However, I ran into an issue when I installed two new dependencies.

I added two dependencies, `@google-cloud/storage` and `multer`. When I deployed again, `vercel` logged `ERROR Cannot find module '@google-cloud/storage'`. Changing the import order, the same happens to `multer`.

I double checked both `package.json` and `package_lock.json` have these dependencies. They do.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^6.5.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "helmet": "^6.0.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "jest": "^27.0.3"
  }
```

I double checked this is what actually runs on the vercel servers.

```
importError.packageJsonData = fs.readFileSync(`${process.cwd()}/package.json`, 'utf8');
```

The `package.json` on the server has these dependencies listed.

When I did this, I also logged what was in `node_modules`.

```
    importError.nodeModulesDirectory = fs.readdirSync(`${process.cwd()}/node_modules`, { withFileTypes: true })
    .filter((item) => item.isDirectory())
    .map((item) => item.name);
```

The `node_modules` on the server indeed do not have `@google-cloud/storage` and `multer`.

I assumed this is some sort of caching error, so I changed the install command to be `npm cache clean --force  && npm install` unfortunatly this did not work either.

I also switched the branch and pushed to a new branch. I still got the error.

Do you have any advice on how to get `vercel` to install my dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when including an additional node package to my Next app in Vercel. I got around it with the following settings:

```
"scripts": {
        "prep": "npm install next react react-dom eslint rimraf -g && yarn add --dev eslint",
        "dev": "next dev",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start",
        "format": "prettier --ignore-path .prettierignore --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,md}\"",
        "lint": "eslint --ignore-path .eslintignore . --ext ts --ext tsx --ext js --ext jsx",
        "lint:fix": "yarn format & next lint --dir src",
        "clean-cache": "rimraf .next",
        "rimraf": "./node_modules/rimraf/bin.js",
        "clean": "yarn prep && rimraf node_modules"
    },
```

In Vercel, use `yarn clean && yarn install` for the install command.

I also redeployed the application without saving the build cache -- that may be worth trying too.